# Handling multiple windows in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What if one same test case opens more than two windows at the same time ,then how to handle those multiple windows at a time,more specifically if i want my main window to close later and the other windows to close first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```

to select the correct window before calling `driver.close()`.  (If there are no windows left, the browser will close.)

There is more information [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

1.Before opening child windows (By clicking links,etc)

```
parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

2.At each new window

```
    public String getChildHandle(WebDriver driver,String parentWindowHandle)
    {
        String childWindowHandle = null;

        Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator itr = allWindowHandles.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            String temp=(String) itr.next();
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindowHandle))  // you can compare with any handle or you can compare with all existing window handles
            {
                System.out.println("Same as parent handle-> "+temp);
            }
            else
            {
                childWindowHandle = temp;
            }
        }
        return childWindowHandle;
    }
```

3.Close any unwanted window

```
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle/childWindow1/childWindow2);
driver.close();
```